# I have a ros-humble pc and a ros-melodic bot, how should I use the pc to control the bot remotely with rviz

Tags: rviz, mobile-robot, ros-humble

It cound't be control and it shows me `Could not contact ROS master at [http://192.168.1.245:11311], retrying..`.how should I do to resolve it.Should I try to use ros1bridge or install a docker ros-melodic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using ROS1 Bridge to Communicate between ROS1 and ROS2](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/97987/using-ros1-bridge-to-communicate-between-ros1-and-ros2)

Comment: What Operating System and version is on the desktop computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to ros, it's a bad idea to try to configure a mixed ros1 / ros2 system. Debugging the problems you are sure to have requires advanced ros knowledge.

If your physical robot uses melodic, and you want a desktop computer to interact with it, the desktop should run ros melodic too. The best option is to first install Ubuntu 18 on the desktop, but if that is difficult, then the next best thing is to run a Docker container with melodic on your linux desktop computer.

You will have to follow an install guide. There are firewall, networking and graphics configuration you need to do if you want this to work.

Answer (score 0):

ROS1 (Melodic) cannot natively communicate with ROS2 (Humble). There are many questions and great answers here on how to bridge between those, and the  `ros1_bridge` is a valid solution.